# Connecting Snow Leopard 10.6.4 to a Linux shared folder using Samba

Tags: centos, samba, local-area-network, osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to connect to a web server running on `Linux CentOS 5.5` where I've shared a folder. I'm trying to connect to the directory with `Snow Leopart 10.6.4` client without success.

On `CentOS` I've started the `Samba service` and a `Samba user` with his password and then I've tried to connect to the server with the command `smb://10.0.0.7` to reach the IP of the machine and then writing the username and password I've previously created.

The server returns me the list of the shared folders with the leopard specific browser, when I click to the folder I want the browser returns this error (translated from Italian):

**Leopard message:**

```
Connection failed
There was an error on connecting to "smb://10.0.0.7". Please verify the name or the IP of the server, and try again.
```

How can I do to solve the connection problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to mount a folder shared ON your Mac... to your CentOS box... you don't need the samba server... just the client package.  Simply make sure your Mac has the folder shared using samba... and on your centos box do the following:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=someuser,password=somepassword //mac-ip/sharename /whereevever/you/want
```

If you're trying to go the other way around, I'm sorry... I just don't know very much about Macs.  I know there are samba packages available... and the commands should be the same.

According to the error you got, it appears that no smb type connection could be made to that IP.  Do you have a firewall running?  You probably need to poke holes in it to allow connectivity.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been too much clear, I'm trying to connect with Leopard to a shared folder of CentOS machine via Samba.

I think it's something on smb.conf file but I'm not sure, because the problem is started with the Leopard 10.6.4 version.

I don't know how I can fix it